# Unable to build Maven project after I manually deleted Target Folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I wanted to check-in the code in svn and did not want to save binary files so I had deleted `Target` folder which is automatically created by maven.  Problem is ever since I did that, maven build is failing.

Here is what all I have tried:

1. `mvn clean install`
2. `mvn clean compile -DskipTests=true install`
3. cleaned all the folders manually and built it again.
4. Eclipse is able to built it.

Interestingly, eclipse does not show a sub-node titled `Maven Dependencies` for this project anymore, for the other projects works fine. I haven't modified the POM files at all.

Pastebin is blocked here so attaching the build output here.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
[INFO] 23 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Extractors ........................................ SUCCESS [0.125s]
[INFO] GenericExtractor .................................. FAILURE [0.687s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.968s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 10 15:36:44 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project GenericExtractor: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\DelimitedExtractor.java:[8,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\CoreExtractor.java:[11,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\CoreExtractor.java:[13,37] package com.ABCInc.ef.common.core.caching does not exist
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\CoreExtractor.java:[14,37] package com.ABCInc.ef.common.core.caching does not exist
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\DelimitedExtractor.java:[17,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.DelimitedExtractor<TKey,TValue>
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\FieldInfo.java:[5,31] package org.springframework.util does not exist
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\CoreExtractor.java:[22,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.CoreExtractor<TKey,TValue>
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\application\Launcher.java:[6,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\application\Launcher.java:[7,34] package org.springframework.context does not exist
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\application\Launcher.java:[8,42] package org.springframework.context.support does not exist
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\application\Launcher.java:[19,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.application.Launcher
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\CoreExtractor.java:[22,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.CoreExtractor<TKey,TValue>
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\CoreExtractor.java:[148,3] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ICacheManager
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.CoreExtractor<TKey,TValue>
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\CoreExtractor.java:[148,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable CacheManagerFactory
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.CoreExtractor<TKey,TValue>
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\DelimitedExtractor.java:[17,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.DelimitedExtractor<TKey,TValue>
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\FieldInfo.java:[15,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable ReflectionUtils
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.FieldInfo
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\FieldInfo.java:[16,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable ReflectionUtils
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.FieldInfo
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\FieldInfo.java:[49,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable ReflectionUtils
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.FieldInfo
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\FieldInfo.java:[55,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable ReflectionUtils
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.FieldInfo
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\core\FieldInfo.java:[78,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable ReflectionUtils
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.core.FieldInfo
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\application\Launcher.java:[19,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.application.Launcher
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\application\Launcher.java:[28,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ApplicationContext
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.application.Launcher
[ERROR] \ABCInc\DEV\GemFireCode\src\java\Extractors\GenericExtractor\src\main\java\com\ABCInc\ef\extractors\application\Launcher.java:[28,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
[ERROR] location: class com.ABCInc.ef.extractors.application.Launcher
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project GenericExtractor: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :GenericExtractor
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ABCInc.ef.extractors</groupId>
    <artifactId>Extractors</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Extractors</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <modules>
        <module>GenericExtractor</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.14</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: Looks like you cleaned out some dependent jars by accident.  `org.apache.`* and `org.springframework.`* are missing.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?  @KeithRandall is correct, it looks like you're missing some dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Keith! I thought so too, but I can see the files and folders in my maven repository. Moreover other projects that use these jars can be built using Maven, it is only this project that is causing trouble.

Comment: @davidfmatheson As suggested, I have attached the POM.

Comment: For future reference, `mvn clean` will delete the target folder, probably in a safer fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `pom.xml`, you should specify dependencies within a top-level `<dependencies>` element, not within a `<dependencyManagement>` element, like so:

```
<project>
    ...
    <url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: I removed that element and that worked!! As an aside, my other projects have `dependencyManagement` node in pom.xml and still work fine. Anyways, this fix worked for me (failing on some other missing jar, but that can be fixed).

Comment: They probably have both a `dependencyManagement` section and a `dependencies` section.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've only declared a `<dependencyManagement>` section in your POM. In order for the dependencies to actually be added to the compile-time classpath you need to also declare them in the `<dependencies>` block directly under the root of the POM.